# PHP Composer can't parse composer.json file for my project

Tags: php, json, composer-php, ratchet

I have successfully installed Composer in the root directory (that was the default choice) on my Linux/Apache server using their installation guide.

http://socketo.me/docs/install

It says I need to "create a file called composer.json in your project folder". So I created that file (with the contents they gave on top of their's page) using the notepad and filezilla to download the file to my application's root directory.

Then I open Putty and type:
`cd /var/www/websocket` (application directory, where already was placed json file)

Then I run Composer using:

```
php ~/composer.phar install
```

and get following error:

> [Seld\JsonLint\ParsingException] "./composer.json" does not contain
>   valid JSON Parse error on line 1:    php ~/composer.phar    ^
>   Expected one of: 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['

My composer.json file contains, in accordance to instructions,

> php ~/composer.phar require cboden/ratchet

What I should to do to install it properly?

Comment: error says it all. Post your json file contents.

Comment: Once you have composer.phar on your system (for this documentation, we're going to assume it's in your home directory) create a file called composer.json in your project folder. Inside that file copy and paste the JSON from the top of this page. So, composer.json file contains: "php ~/composer.phar require cboden/ratchet" (without ")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

composer.json should only contain valid `json` string. Following is not a `json`

```
php ~/composer.phar require cboden/ratchet
```

Replace `composer.json` content with the following,

```
{
  "require" : {
     "php": ">=5.4.2",
     "cboden/Ratchet": "dev-master"
  }
}
```

And then run following command from the same directory that contains `composer.json`

```
php ~/composer.phar update
```

For detailed schema of composer.json [read this](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md).

Comment: I don't know, why they pointed to the wrong string for composer.json file in their instruction. Or may be I missed correct pointing on their instructions' page.

Comment: @Areso- this sentence `Inside that file copy and paste the JSON from the top of this page.` is completely pointless as there is no valid `json` ontop of the page. This makes it hard for new user to install it. Although seasoned `composer` user will figure it out. But it is just an ignorance on their part.

Comment: This is a documentation bug. I opened an issue for you: https://github.com/ratchetphp/Ratchet/issues/338

Comment: @Sven- Great job. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i know i am late but just incase someone runs into this error

if you are using brew , all you need to do is  `brew install composer`

if its already installed it will update it and set it all up for you

hope this helps someone.